# vmap gives inconsistent shape error when trying to calculate gradient per sample

Tags: python, jax

I am trying to implement a two layer neural network and get the gradient of the second layer per sample.

My code looks like this:

```
x = jnp.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=jnp.float32)
y = jnp.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=jnp.float32)

W1 = jnp.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=jnp.float32)
W2 = random.uniform(key, shape=(10,), minval=1, maxval=2, dtype=jnp.float32)
b = jnp.linspace(0, -9, 10, dtype=jnp.float32)
b = jnp.reshape(b, (1,10))

def predict(W1, W2, b, x):
  f1 = jnp.einsum('i,j->ji', W1, x)+b
  f1 = nn.relu(f1)
  f2 = jnp.einsum('i,ji->j', W2, f1)
  return f2

def loss(W1, W2, b, x, y):
  preds = predict(W1, W2, b, x)
  return jnp.mean(jnp.square(y-preds))

perex_grads = vmap(grad(loss, argnums=1), in_axes= (0, None, 0, 0, 0))
pers_grads = perex_grads(W1, W2, b, x, y)
```

I ran loss and can do `grad(loss)` just fine. Running `vmap` is the actual problem.

The exact error I get is:

```
ValueError: vmap got inconsistent sizes for array axes to be mapped:
arg 0 has shape (10,) and axis 0 is to be mapped
arg 1 has shape (10,) and axis None is to be mapped
arg 2 has shape (1, 10) and axis 0 is to be mapped
arg 3 has shape (11,) and axis 0 is to be mapped
arg 4 has shape (11,) and axis 0 is to be mapped
so
arg 0 has an axis to be mapped of size 10
arg 2 has an axis to be mapped of size 1
args 3, 4 have axes to be mapped of size 11
```

It is my first time using Jax, and my google search didn't help me resolve the issue, plus the documentation was not very clear to me. I'd appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is exactly what the error message says: in order to vmap an operation over multiple arrays, the dimension of the mapped axes in each array must be equal. In your arrays, the dimensions are not equal: you passed `in_axes=(0, None, 0, 0, 0)` for arguments `W1, W2, b, x, y`, but `W1.shape[0] = 10`, `b.shape[0] = 1`, `x.shape[0] = 11`, and `y.shape[0] = 11`.

Because these are not equal, you get this error. To prevent this error, you should only vmap over array axes of the same length.

For example, if you want the gradients with respect to `W2` computed per pair of `W1, W2` inputs, it might look something like this (note the updated `predict` function and updated `in_axes`):

```python
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random, nn, grad, vmap

key = random.PRNGKey(0)

x = jnp.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=jnp.float32)
y = jnp.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=jnp.float32)

W1 = jnp.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=jnp.float32)
W2 = random.uniform(key, shape=(10,), minval=1, maxval=2, dtype=jnp.float32)
b = jnp.linspace(0, -9, 10, dtype=jnp.float32)
b = jnp.reshape(b, (1,10))

def predict(W1, W2, b, x):
  # Since you're vmapping over W1 and W2, your function needs to
  # handle scalar values, so we cast to 1D if necessary.
  W1 = jnp.atleast_1d(W1)
  W2 = jnp.atleast_1d(W2)

  f1 = jnp.einsum('i,j->ji', W1, x)+b
  f1 = nn.relu(f1)
  f2 = jnp.einsum('i,ji->j', W2, f1)
  return f2

def loss(W1, W2, b, x, y):
  preds = predict(W1, W2, b, x)
  return jnp.mean(jnp.square(y-preds))

perex_grads = vmap(grad(loss, argnums=1), in_axes= (0, 0, None, None, None))
pers_grads = perex_grads(W1, W2, b, x, y)
```

Comment: I would like to get the per sample gradients with respect to ```W2```. I was following the example shown here https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/jax/blob/main/docs/jax-101/04-advanced-autodiff.ipynb#scrollTo=tFLyd9ifw4GG

Comment: OK, that makes sense. See my updated answer.

Comment: I don't get an error anymore, but the output is still not what I want. I have 11 samples, and W2 has 10 components, hence the per sample gradient should be a matrix of size 11x10 (or 11x10). Currently the output shape is (10,). Also, just to be clear, my input-output pairs are ```x``` and ```y```. ```W2``` is my weight of which I take gradient. I think the problem is that ```W2``` is a vector (not a scalar), hence I probably need to find another way to tell Jax that.

Comment: OK - when you said "per sample gradients with respect to `W2`" I thought you wanted a gradent per entry in `W2`. Hopefully my comments & example above are enough to help you solve your problem. Best of luck!